# How i can define a hierarchy inside same class

Tags: php

Starting from this pseudocode:

```
class myClass {

    public function foo() {
       // something
    }

    public
    function f1() {
        return "something one";
    }

    public
    function f2() {
        return "something two";
    }

}
```

How i can modify this code for to have something like so:

```
$myclass = new myclass();
echo $myClass->foo()->f1(); // display: something one
echo $myClass->foo()->f2(); // display: something two
```

Is possible to do it? I have tried to find something but not solved.
Thanks.

Comment: Hierarchy? I think you mean order of execution?

Comment: You should use inheritance.

Comment: Hello, about your suggest i have looked, but not is same what i mean.  I not want a extension of a class but want define a hieararchy. I have solved  defining a function which instance a object called from other class, but i want try to do it from same class. Understand what i mean?

Comment: isn't the answer useful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to remember is return the `instance of class` otherwise on calling next method, it return **Fatal Error**

```
class myclass {

protected $fooVar;

public function foo($string) {
    $this->fooVar = $string;

    return $this;
}

public function myFunc($string) {
    return $this->fooVar . " || " . $string;
}

}


$class = new myClass();

// output:: myString || my new sexy text
echo $class->foo("myString")->myFunc("my new sexy text");
```